# Module can import at console, but not within script

Tags: python, linux, module, python-module, env

I am having a strange problem when I run a script, I can not load `pymongo`, but it is available when I run the hashbang interpreter (`/usr/bin/env python`).

The original call `import pymongo` was buried quite deep in a class, but even if I call it at line 1, it fails.

Why is this?

Here is some output from the python console showing `pymongo` is available:

```
# /usr/bin/env python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 23 2013, 14:02:51)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo
>>>
```

Here are the first three lines of a script

```
# head -n 3 ./app/app.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymongo
```

Here is the failure:

```
# python ./app/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pymongo
ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

But running with `/usr/bin/env` works okay... why?

```
# /usr/bin/env python ./app/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app/app.py", line 37, in <module>
    db = backend.flowbackend.getBackendObject(config.db_backend, config.db_host, config.db_port, config.db_user, config.db_password, config.db_name)
      File "./app/../lib/backend/flowbackend.py", line 268, in getBackendObject
    return MongoBackend(host, port, user, password, databaseName)
  File "./app/../lib/backend/mongobackend.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "./app/../lib/backend/mongobackend.py", line 62, in connect
    self.conn = pymongo.Connection(self.host, self.port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 220, in     __init__
    max_pool_size, document_class, tz_aware, _connect, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 336, in     __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: could not connect to 127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 111]     Connection refused
```

Comment: python looks for modules in the places listed in `sys.path`. Maybe comparing this variable for both cases helps.

Comment: probably the script modifies `sys.path`?

Comment: you most likely have multiple versions of python installed on your computer. the path for python in what you're calling "original" is probably not the same python that the hashbang enterpreter has.

Comment: I've added some output that tackles the topic all three of you brought up.

Comment: looks like `mata` is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with pyserial, but in my case my script file has name serial.py, so when I try to import serial it can't recognize my package. I just rename my file and works fine.

Comment: That's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-a-library-from-or-near-a-script-with-the-same-name-raises-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Check .pythonrc in your home directory.  The console executes it (if present), scripts don't.  It's the only thing I can think of right now.  Maybe it sets sys.path such that pymongo is accessible.

I assume that you're trying to run the script as you, that is, the same user that starts the interactive interpreter.  If not, well, that could also be a cause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've updated the original post showing that when I run `/usr/bin/env python`, `pymongo` is available.  It strikes me as quite strange, but it shows that I might not understand `env` as I should.

Answer (score 0):

Running `/usr/bin/python` was 2.6.6 and `/usr/local/bin/python` was 2.7.4.  `pip-python` was affecting `/usr/bin/python`.

```
# pip-python -E /usr/local/bin/python freeze
distribute==0.6.10
iniparse==0.3.1
pycurl==7.19.0
pygpgme==0.1
urlgrabber==3.9.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
yum-metadata-parser==1.1.2

# pip-python install pymongo
...

# pip-python -E /usr/local/bin/python freeze
distribute==0.6.10
iniparse==0.3.1
pycurl==7.19.0
pygpgme==0.1
pymongo==2.5
urlgrabber==3.9.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
yum-metadata-parser==1.1.2

# pip-python -E /usr/bin/python freeze
distribute==0.6.10
iniparse==0.3.1
pycurl==7.19.0
pygpgme==0.1
pymongo==2.5
urlgrabber==3.9.1
yum-metadata-parser==1.1.2
```

Both instances must refer to the same `libs`.  Okay fine...

Comment: I don't really understand this; are you saying that running `/usr/bin/env python` at your terminal runs a different Python executable to just running `python` at your terminal? That's surprising to me.