# Why does my import fail in a script, but it can be execute by a python console?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a Python script called `my_app.py` as following:

```
from my_app.source.module1 import func1
func1()
```

If I execute the script `my_app.py` by the following command:

```
> python my_app.py
```

it raises the Exception `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "my_app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_app.source.module1 import func1
  File "/home/<myuser>/my_app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_app.source.module1 import func1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app.source'; 'my_app' is not a package
```

I'm sure that in my system is installed a package called `my_app` because I can execute, without error, the previous `import` by a Python console:

```
> python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 20 2020, 13:26:22) 
[GCC 10.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from my_app.source.module1 import func1
>>>
```

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177939/module-can-import-at-console-but-not-within-script) which seems very closer to mine, but it is not useful.

Could someone show me where is my error?

Comment: can you show me the directory that `myapp.py` file contain.

Comment: Yes it is saved in `/home/<myuser>/my_app.py`, in the error message you can see that the Exception refers to line 1 of that file.

Comment: then please add `__init__.py` where myapp.py file is exist.

Comment: @Tanveer, thanks for your comment. With it I have indirectly found the solution of the problem: the name of the script is the same of the name of the package. So I have changed the name of `my_app.py` to `my-app.py` and the import starts working. Before writing an answer, the question has been closed.

Comment: thank you for adding this stuff in my head.. hahaha );